# Google Universal Analytics Real-time not working

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to integrate Google Universal Analytics into my website. I have started to see basic reporting (page views, uniques, etc.) under **Behavior > Overview**

But still see nothing for real-time reporting under
**Realtime > Overview**

And I cannot seem to get any events to fire.

I have this code snippet at the very end of :

```js
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-41505208-2', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  //ga(‘set’, ‘&uid’, {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.

  $(".sub-menu li a").click(function(){
    //window.analytics.trackEvent('nav', 'tap', 'filter');
    //ga('nav', 'tap', 'filter');
    //ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'nav', eventAction: 'tap', eventLabel: 'filter'});
    ga('send', 'event', 'nav', 'tap', 'filter');
  });
</script>
```

I have tried to move my sample event to other places with no luck ... also not sure which of the event lines is the one you're supposed to use with Universal, so have tried each one with no luck.

So frustrating. The old Google Analytics always worked so easily.

I have this site located at a directory under another site, does that matter?

- Analytics code is on: http://dmlapps.com/dogpeople/index.html
- Google Analytics is setup at: http://dmlapps.com/dogpeople
- Website is at: http://dmlapps.com/dogpeople

Comment: I also have this in Google groups, but no answer yet.
https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/analytics/00448269-e98f-4a46-ab94-8837c1622640%40googleproductforums.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Comment: OK, as soon as I posted this question, I am now seeing real-time visits coming from StackOverflow. Is it ignoring my devices?

Comment: Have you set up any filtering to exclude your own visits? For example, IP-based filters?

Comment: No I have not setup anything specific. All I did was include that code snippet on the index.html file.

Comment: Someone from Canada just visited the site and showed up in Real Time reports, but it's yet to show my activity on Real Time reports.

Comment: Chances are that I am that Canadian. Do you have [GA Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) installed? Can you see if Pageviews or other hits are sent from your browser?

Comment: Yes, I have that installed in Chrome, and it appears page views are being sent... my events are not firing still (if you select a category from the filter menu at left, it's supposed to send an event telling me you did that).

The other issue is I don't know why my personal activity is not being included in Real Time reports. I have tried a couple browsers and my phone.

Comment: Screenshot from GA Debugger:
http://davidmlester.com/samples/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-30%20at%209.21.29%20AM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Custom Events are not firing because at the time of the evaluation, `$(".sub-menu li a")` does not match any element in the DOM, as it has not finished loading.

You should wrap your call in a `$(document).ready()` callback:

```js
<script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-41505208-2', 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
   //ga(‘set’, ‘&uid’, {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.

   // From your original post:
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.sub-menu li a').click(function () {
         //window.analytics.trackEvent('nav', 'tap', 'filter');
         //ga('nav', 'tap', 'filter');
         //ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'nav', eventAction: 'tap', eventLabel: 'filter'});
         ga('send', 'event', 'nav', 'tap', 'filter');
      });
   });
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could also use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, for live evaluation:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.sub-menu li a', function () {
    ga('send', 'event', 'nav', 'tap', 'filter');
});
```

Comment: That fixed everything!

Comment: Events firing and now my devices are registering!

Comment: Good job! Sent some Canadian sub-menu hits your way so you can validate :)